# Prepare a power cable for a 7 kW kitchen stove

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am replacing a kitchen stove, and both have the same power requirements (7 kW), so the installation is OK. I have made the replacement up to a cable connection. The new cable has something what looks like a copper shield, but I don't have any experience, so I wonder: Should it be removed before inserting to the PVC strip connector?

Phase one is a single one going to the connector, and phase two was combined with the oven cable, the same as zero and ground.

[image: Power cable]

[EDIT] By looking more at the wires, this looks like more like gold than copper color(?). Is it here to save wires until the connection or to decrease the resistance of the connection?

Comment: The ferrules (see the answer by Transistor) are probably made of brass.  It's a harder alloy of copper.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those are a type of crimp ferrule.

They bind the wires tightly together giving the advantages of a solid conductor at the terminal, prevent stray strands getting bent backwards (short-circuit and electrocution risk) or missing the terminals (reduced contact area with resultant increase in temperature).

Comment: @U. Windl, I disapproved your edit with link to the Wikipedia crimp connector page. These are not connectors. But thank you for trying to improve my post.

Comment: I have first pushed the bare wire to connector, flatten it a bit, then crimped one over it and tighten the screw hard. Connection looks very tight and solid. Then I have tested it by measuring the temperature cold, and then after two minutes after both appliances maxed. Connector temperature was only 1 deg C warmer. I guess this is good.

Comment: @Transistor How about linking to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_wire_ferrule instead?

Comment: @watbywbarif In addition to the benefits Transistor already mentioned in his answer, using a ferrule is necessary for securing stranded wires into screw terminals. Solid core wires can handle being crushed by a screw, they'll just deform a bit. Stranded wires won't, as it's possible the screw will shear off individual strands in isolation, ultimately lowering the contact area, loosening the connection, etc. Ferrules effectively turn stranded wire into a single solid core.

Comment: @Alexander, there's a photo of the crimp ferrule in the question and I've given it a name in my answer. I think the problem is solved and it should be quite clear what it is, what it's for and how it might be applied but feel free to post your own answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Transistor I agree, after your response I checked out more about ferrules and how to join wires with ferrules, but as I lacked the tools and ferrules I had to improvise. But I will buy some to have ready for next time. Thx!